# Spring WebTestClient JSON LocalDate decode

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

When using `WebTestClient` in Spring Boot 2.0.1 I get different formatted dates depending on how I bind the test client see code below.

So how can I get the `WebTestClient.bindToController` to return `LocalDate` formatted as `2018-04-13`? When I call `WebTestClient.bindToServer()` I get expected format.

```
@RestController
public class TodayController {
  @GetMapping("/today")
  public Map<String, Object> fetchToday() {
    return ImmutableMap.of("today", LocalDate.now());
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class TodayControllerTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  private int randomPort;

  @Autowired
  private TodayController controller;

  @Test
  void fetchTodayWebTestClientBoundToController() {
     WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToController(controller)
        .configureClient()
        .build();
    webTestClient.get().uri("/today")
        .exchange()
        .expectBody()
        .json("{\"today\":[2018,4,13]}");
}

@Test
void fetchTodayWebTestClientBoundToServer() {
    WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + randomPort)
        .build();

    webTestClient.get().uri("/today")
        .exchange()
        .expectBody()
        .json("{\"today\":\"2018-04-13\"}");
}
```

Comment: Both tests are green when I test on a project generated on start.spring.io. Could you double check and share a repro project in case you reproduce it?

Comment: They are both green but the expected date formats are different was expecting them to both return today formatted as `2018-04-13`

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out I need to set the Jackson decoder/encoder when using `WebTestClient.bindToController`. e.g.

```
@Test
  public void fetchTodayWebTestClientBoundToController() {
     WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToController(controller)
         .httpMessageCodecs((configurer) -> {
             CodecConfigurer.DefaultCodecs defaults = configurer.defaultCodecs();
             defaults.jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, new MimeType[0]));
             defaults.jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper, new MimeType[0]));
         })
        .configureClient()
        .build();
    webTestClient.get().uri("/today")
        .exchange()
        .expectBody()
        .json("{\"today\":\"2018-04-30\"}");
  }
```

More detailed answer from [Spring boot project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12997)

Comment: If using `bindToController` is not a hard requirement, you can also just autowire `WebTestClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this file with configuration

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer;
import org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder;
import org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;

@Configuration
@Import(JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
public class JacksonTestConfiguration {
   
    @Bean
    WebFluxConfigurer webFluxConfigurer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new WebFluxConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper));
                configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper));
            }
        };
    }
}
```